# Azure API Management trace and debug

Tags: debugging, trace, azure-api-management

I have several policies in Azure APIM that I want to test. I can't use the Developer Console to call these APIs so I call these APIs via PostMan for example.
When I have issues in the policies (i.e Validate JWT policy for example), I want to know how I can have a full trace of the calls made by the policies behind the scene (client->APIM, APIM to backend and so on), but I don't know where I can find that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [debug APIs by using request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector).

This is enabled by setting a header with key `Ocp-Apim-Trace` and value `true`. This is automatically set when making requests from the Azure Portal.

> You have to a subscription key with tracing enabled

With this header present, the response will contain a header `ocp-apim-trace-location` with value set to a URL pointing to the trace.

Comment: how we can get old trace details

Comment: The traces themselves are JSON files stored in an internal storage account whose link is in the header. They expire after some time. You will have to persist them yourself if you require.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you could [log to application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights) or [log to event hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs).